# Spring saml successRedirectHandler

Tags: redirect, single-sign-on, spring-saml

I'm trying to redirect user already authenticated via saml to a specific default page according to his role.

For example:

```
         if user has role A redirect to https://localhost:8443/myApp/A_default_page

         if user has role B redirect to https://localhost:8443/myApp/B_default_page
```

The problem in saml, we can définite just one :

```
<bean id="successRedirectHandler"  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <!-- <property name="useReferer" value="true"/> -->
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="here default url "/>
```

Any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler and override method

```
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
```

Then you can use the authentication object to read the roles and choose the redirect url.

Also you may consider using SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler instead of SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler if you want this custom logic.